# After receiving JSON how can i create the row to show in Django view

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Suppose i received the JSON object in my jquery function

`[{"pk": 38, "model": "app.book", "fields": {"book_name": "Learn JSON", "book_branch": "Web"}}]`

Now i want to know that how can i create the table row which i can append in the existing Table.
provded that i don't know the fields in object.

Because I have to use same function on many objects which have different fields so i don't want to hard code the fields. I would like to get the field name automatically from JSON.

I have many examples from internet but they hardcode the fields

Comment: Don't see how this is related to Django.

Comment: I Genertaed the JSON from Django serialize function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you already parsed the JSON using jQuery.

You can simply use a [`for...in` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop to iterate over all properties of the object.